# Display DIV only on specific subpage

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to display a Joomla module or a div, but only on specific subpages.

Example: trying to display this

```
<div><?php echo $this['widgets']->render('module'); ?></div>
```

Only on `www.example.com/products/item1` and other subpages of `/products`

But NOT on:

```
www.example.com/
```

or

```
www.example.com/products/
```

I can't find a PHP or JS script to do that, nor is it possible to do it with the native Joomla features.

How to do that?

Comment: Is this a Yootheme module by any chance?

Comment: Yes it is, but I want to use this script for divs that are not Yootheme modules ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) on the [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

```
<?php if (preg_match("/products\/.+/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])): ?>
    <div><?php echo $this['widgets']->render('module'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The expression `/products\/.+/` sees if `products` is in the url and a slash and some content follows it.

Comment: good job +1, but I think that you need to reverse your condition, as I understand if not existe products then render

Comment: I don't think so, OP seems to indicate that they want the div to show on subpages of products/, which this will do.

Comment: Woot, thx guys, will test it right away and let you know in minutes!

Comment: You are a beast, I wish I knew codding better! THANKS :)

Comment: Favorited (and even upvoted the Q) just for this snippet, cool!

Comment: Ok so let's add some challenge here.

I realize that there exist `www.example.com/products/item` and `www.example.com/products/categories`. And I don't want the div to appear on the last one.

I tried using `/item\/.+/` instead but realized there also exist `www.example.com/videos/item`

Meaning that I get the same div to appear both under `/products` and `/videos`. And I would like to use different div for each pages.

Conclusion, I'm looking for something that display the div on pages `item` that are only under `products`

Having fun now ? Thanks :)

Comment: To not display on a 'categories' page you can use this pattern: `/products\/(?!categories).+/`. As for displaying different divs on the different pages, you can change `products` to whatever page you'd like instead.